# Aptana studio 3 en python no muestra ventana de salida

Tags: python

Simplemente escribí:

```
print "HOLA"
```

y me muestra:

> Finding files... done.
>   Importing test modules ... done.
>   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
>   Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
>   
>   OK

Answer (score 0):

No he trabajado directamente con Aptana, pero recuerdo que es un IDE Eclipse con añadidos para programación móvil.

La salida se hace a una *vista* llamada *"Console"*. Es posible que la tengas minimizada. Búscala en el menú `Window -> Show View`.

Otra opción es *resetear* la perspectiva. Asegúrate que tienes elegida la perspectiva de *Python* y resetéala desde el menú `Windows -> Perspective`.

Quizás la mejor opción es que siempre muestre la cónsola cuando se produzca una salida o un error. En preferencias, busca las opciones de `Run/Debug -> Console` y activa las opciones para que muestre la cónsola:

[[image: Opciones cónsola]]

Es el diálogo de preferencias para eclipse. Espero que se vea parecido en Aptana.